# Error using built-in pipe in my custom pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

Built-in pipes are working fine in my components, but not in my custom pipe.
Apart from this my pipe is working just fine. I can't see what could be the problem since I imported Pipe.

Here is the code with the erros:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Perso } from './perso';

@Pipe({ name: 'startsWithPersoPipe' })
export class StartsWithPersoPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(Persos: Perso[], search:string){
    // without this if will crash as Persos is null until it gets its data from server
    if(Persos == null) {
      return null;
    }
    for(let perso of Persos){
      console.log(perso.nom); // works fine
      console.log(perso.nom | lowercase); // ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: lowercase is not defined
    }
    return Persos.filter(p => (p.nom) && (p.nom).startsWith(search)); // works fine
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log(perso.nom | lowercase);
```

Is not supposed to work.

```
| somePipe
```

is only supported in templates in binding expressions.

You can use pipes in code like

```
constructor(private lowercase: LowerCasePipe) {}

console.log(this.lowercase.transform(perso.nom));
```

You also don't import `LowerCasePipe`

Instead of using the pipe you can also just call the method on the string

```
perso.nom && perso.nom.toLowerCase()
```